# Python: MemoryError vs OverflowError vs instant-system-freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, range, out-of-memory

Last day, solving another [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives) I fell into trouble managing a **big** `for i in range(n)` cycle.

I observed that `python` throws me different errors, **depending on how was big the `x` variable**.

Here is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example:

```
for i in range(x):
    pass
```

Where:

- if `x = 10**20` I got an **`OverflowError`**, 
  exactly: `OverflowError: range() result has too many items`.
- else if `x = 10**15` I got a **`MemoryError`**.
- else if `x = 10**9` I got an **`instant-system-freeze`** and I have to hard-reset my pc. Rarely, instead of freezing, my pc fill up about 5GB of swap, becoming extremely slow.

I tried to understand the meaning of the python [built-in exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#module-exceptions):

- [`OverflowError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError):

  > Raised when the result of an arithmetic operation is too large to be represented. This cannot occur for long integers [...] and for most operations with plain integers, which return a long integer instead. [...]

  This mean that integers should never throw this exception; the cause of this exception is the `range()` with too many items, so I suppose that also `10**15` will throw the same exception but I got a different one...
- [`MemoryError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError):

  > Raised when an operation runs out of memory but the situation may still be rescued (by deleting some objects). [...]

  Which object should I delete to rescue this situation? It simply exit, so the situation cannot be rescued...

  And if it *feels* that there's too much `ram` usage, why it freezes my pc with `10**9`?

---

Finally, my question is:

**Why I'm getting 3 different result, only depending on the value stored in the `x` variable?**

---

**NOTE**:

- I know the existence of [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), that hasn't this problem, but my question is about [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).
- I think that the values used to throw the exception may change, depending on your hardware.
- My `Python` version: `2.7.6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `range` tries to build an **entire** list with as many items as `x`.

For the *instant-swap-of-the-death* case, you can estimate that, assuming 64 bits and a fixed 8 byte integer, `x = 10**9` is worth about 8 Go. So if you have no more than that (take into account already used RAM) you can see why the system swap.

Going further down, a `MemoryError` is probably raised if the function could not allocate a chunk big enough to hold the result (which in the case of `10**15` seems quite big).

<s>I don't know the implementation detail of `range` but it might be using the `OverflowError` to ensure an absolute maximum number of elements (maybe in a way to prevent `MemoryError`, based on real available memory).</s>
As mentioned in the comment by @ShadowRanger, an `OverflowError` is raised if the length of the result cannot fit into a `size_t` variable (`2**31` (32 bit) or `2**63` (64 bit)) as it cannot initialize such a list.

As you mentioned, xrange does not have this issue because it does not generate the entire list but generates a single value each time you iterate it. That why iterator/generator are memory efficient.

---

So I took a quick look, you can see [in the 2.7 source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Objects/rangeobject.c#l90) why it throws an `OverflowError`.

Comment: The `OverflowError` is because CPython uses a signed `size_t` to represent the length of sequences; it's not possible for it to even _begin_ initializing a `list` that would have `2**31` (32 bit) or `2**63` (64 bit) or more elements, because the variable that stores the number of elements can't represent a number that large.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ha yes, you're right. I haven't work with typed language for a while so I begin to forget the basics... =o

Answer (score 0):

`range(x)` will first create a list of size `x`, and then fill it with integers. The effects are:

- `x = 10**20`: [OverflowError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError), because a list can only hold [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) (typically `2**31 - 1` or `2**63 - 1` for 32 bit and 64 bit builds respectively) items.
- `x = 10**15`: [MemoryError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError), because there is insufficient memory to allocate a (uninitialized) list of size x.
- `x = 10**9`:  A list of size x will be created; then for *every* integer `i < x`, a new int object will be created and written to disk; each of which requires a memory allocation.  (Which eventually might or might not lead to a MemoryError.)  This puts a big load on CPU and memory, which then slows down your machine.

In summary, for the first two cases it is obvious to python that the task cannot complete, and it raises an exception.  In the third case, it thinks it might be able to achieve the task, albeit slowly.